# Deserialize List<ArrayList> object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am trying to de-serialize a XML to object but I am getting stuck at one situation. Can anyone please help me out here.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Level>
  <Warp_Blocks>
        <Warp_Block>
            <Block row="7" col="7" />
            <Block row="2" col="7" />
        </Warp_Block>
        <Warp_Block>
            <Block row="4" col="4" />
            <Block row="3" col="7" />
        </Warp_Block>
  </Warp_Blocks>
</Level>
```

Code:

```
  [XmlRoot("Level")]
   public class LData
    {
        [XmlArray("Warp_Blocks")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Warp_Block",typeof(WarpBlock),IsNullable = false)]
        public List<WarpBlock> WarpBlocks;
    }
   public class LBlock
   {
      [XmlAttribute("row")]
      public int row;
      [XmlAttribute("col")]
      public int col;
   }
   public class WarpBlock
   {
      [XmlArray("Warp_Block")]
      [XmlArrayItem("Block",typeof(LBlock),IsNullable= false)]
      public List<LBlock> WarpBlocks;

      public WarpBlock()
      {
            WarpBlocks = new List<LBlock>();
      }
   }
```

I am able to de-serialize to one level i.e. I get a List of Item objects but the individual Item objects don't contain the List of Block objects. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `class Items` - either this is your problem or we're not looking at the real code.

Comment: How do you deserialize ? If you're using `XmlSerializer`, you might need to make your classes public.

Comment: @Henk - Can't post the original code here..so had to make this example.. but I hope you get what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Nekresh - Yes. All classes are public.

Comment: @Sharath: I would prefer a copy-paste of the original, maybe with some deletions. This has a high risk of us chasing your typos instead of the problem.

Comment: @Henk - Changes made.. this is the class i am working with

Answer (score 4):

Change your LData class to this:

```
[XmlRoot("Level")]
public class LData
{
    [XmlElement("Warp_Blocks")]
    public List<WarpBlock> WarpBlocks;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I don't know why it is not reading your second Warp_Block. The only possible reason I think can be that you are doing something else than what you have posted in the question. Here is the full example:

```
[XmlRoot("Level")]
public class LData
{
    [XmlElement("Warp_Blocks")]
    public List<WarpBlock> WarpBlocks;
}
public class LBlock
{
    [XmlAttribute("row")]
    public int row;
    [XmlAttribute("col")]
    public int col;
}
public class WarpBlock
{
    [XmlArray("Warp_Block")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Block", typeof(LBlock), IsNullable = false)]
    public List<LBlock> WarpBlocks;

    public WarpBlock()
    {
        WarpBlocks = new List<LBlock>();
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string test =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>" +
            "<Level>" +
            "  <Warp_Blocks>" +
            "        <Warp_Block>" +
            "            <Block row=\"7\" col=\"7\" />" +
            "            <Block row=\"2\" col=\"7\" />" +
            "        </Warp_Block>" +
            "        <Warp_Block>" +
            "            <Block row=\"4\" col=\"4\" />" +
            "            <Block row=\"3\" col=\"7\" />" +
            "        </Warp_Block>" +
            "  </Warp_Blocks>" +
            "</Level>";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof (LData));
        LData data = (LData) s.Deserialize(stream);

        foreach (var a in data.WarpBlocks)
            foreach (var b in a.WarpBlocks)
                Console.WriteLine(b.row + ", " + b.col);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It correctly outputs this:

```
7, 7
2, 7
4, 4
3, 7
```

Comment: @Yogesh - Tried this.. so I am able to read the first element into the list, but not the second...

Comment: Which second element are your talking about?

Comment: In the XML above, Warp_Blocks contains two Warp_Block objects, but it is currently reading only the first one..

Comment: @Yogesh - I have double checked the code, and they are similar. The only difference being I am using XmlTextReader to read the XML from a file and then de-serializing it.

Comment: @Yogesh - My apologies.. this works, but not exactly the way I want. The output is actually a WarpBlock object that contains all 4 Block items. But in reality what I want is each 2 WarpBlock objects containing two Blocks within them.

Comment: Update your question with the exact xml and the exact output you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are doing here, but there is a gotcha with deserialization (at least binary deserialization. I don't know, but I suspect that it is the same for XML serialization). On deserializing a `List<T>` or a `Dictionary<S,T>`, the list is filled with `null` values (or default value if it is a value type) until the deserialization constructor has been exited. Only after exiting the constructor is the list filled with the actual, deserialized `T`s.

This means that if you want to do something with the list, it cannot be done in the constructor. You can instead make a method which contains any work which needs to be done with the list, and as long as it is annotated with the `[OnDeserializedAttribute]` attribute, it will be called **after** the list has been filled but **before** the deserialization returns. The method can have any name.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) for details.

Comment: I tried this.. for the WarpBlock class, but no change in the output