# Can I deserialize an XML element which is an array of arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deserialize List<ArrayList> object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016558/deserialize-listarraylist-object)

I am really struggling to deserialize the following XML into a C# object;

```
<docRoot>
  ...
  <doc-sets>
     <docs>
      <atom:link rel="related" href="http://blah.com/1" title="abc" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
      <atom:link rel="related" href="http://blah.com/2" title="abc2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
     </docs>
     <docs>
      <atom:link rel="related" href="http://blah.com/1" title="abc" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
      <atom:link rel="related" href="http://blah.com/2" title="abc2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
     </docs>
    ....
  </doc-sets>
</docRoot
```

I have found a previous question which is very similar ([Deserialize List<ArrayList> object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016558/deserialize-listarraylist-object)) but I too have reached the same problem as the original poster.

I can create an object which has a list of all the Links combined, but I want to maintain the fact that there are 2 "docs" elements and keep the links separate for both.

My code so far;

```
    [XmlRoot("docRoot")]
public class DocRoot
{
    [XmlElement("doc-sets")]
    public List<Docs> DocSets;
}
public class Link
{
    [XmlAttribute("href")]
    public string Href;        
}
public class Docs
{
    [XmlArray("docs")]
    [XmlArrayItem("link", typeof(Link), Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public List<Link> Links;

    public Docs()
    {
        Links = new List<Link>();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I keep 2 "Doc" elements containing their own links rather than one combined list of Links?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you have a list of doc-sets with a list of docs with a list of links. Then you're missing the class DocSet:

```
[XmlRoot("docRoot")]
public class DocRoot
{
  [XmlElement("doc-sets")]
  public DocSet DocSets;
}

public class DocSet
{
  [XmlElement("docs")]
  public List<Doc> Docs;
}

public class Doc
{
  [XmlElement("link", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
  public List<Link> Links;
}

public class Link
{
  [XmlAttribute("href")]
  public string Href;        
}
```

Now when deserializing the XML you'll have a list of docs and each docs object has it's own links.

**Edit:**
Apparently it's one doc-sets element with a list of docs with a list of links.

Comment: Apologies, the XML naming is confusing.  There is one "doc-sets" which contains a list of "docs". In turn, "docs" contains a list if "Link".

Comment: @Robbie : I guess Sani's answer also works when DocSets is of type DocSet instead of List<DocSet>

Comment: As @jbl said, Just change the type to DocSet instead of List<DocSet> and you should be on your way. :)